# Remove a property from entity doctrine still looks for it

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I removed a property from my Entity and did

> php app/console doctrine:Scheme:update --force

then

> php app/console cache:clear --env=dev

The database is updated fine, however when I run the code the entity is still looking for the property I deleted.

```
Property myBundle\Entity\Name::$oldproperty does not exist (500 Internal       Server Error)
```

How do I update this.  Note I'm using APC cache? Thanks

Comment: Are you still trying to access the property somewhere in your code?

Comment: @LorenzSchaef no reference in the code

Comment: Did you try to clear Doctrine cache? 
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata && app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query && app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result

Comment: yes I tried that but as I'm using APC cache give me this error "[LogicException]                                                             
  Cannot clear APC Cache from Console, its shared in the Webserver memory and  
   not accessible from the CLI. "

Comment: I had this scenario, I was using the property in one of the queries in DQL. Can you check if this is the case?

Comment: @GAV clear APC (by restarting php - either php-fpm or apache or whatever you've got there).

Comment: Try once to empty your proxy folder. Are you sure there is no doctrine event listener, repository, getter method or something else like that still using this property?

Comment: @JakubZalas yep that sorted it thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you probably not be able to clear the query-cache in CLI (app/console) since the console can't (or is not allowed to) clear the APC Cache. So you had to clear the APC Cache manually.

$ php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result

And if that doesn't work, clear the APC Cache (or whatever cache you use) manually.